# "Reselect" VS "Memoize-One" with "React and Redux"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, memoization, reselect

I'm trying to use some kind of memoization in my workflow with React, and I'm searching for the best and most importantly the **"easiest"** solution to integrate with my workflow that includes `React and Redux`.

I came across many articles talking about memoization in general and some demonstrate the use of "memoize-one" and brace it as the fastest and easiest to get up and running with, and others don't even mention it and talk about "reselect".

I just want to know which is better and easiest and which should I invest in.

Comment: reselect is designed specifically with redux in mind. probably a good fit for you

Answer (score 19):

**Both** libraries **return a function** which **accepts a given numbers of arguments** and **returns a value**:

```
getA(arg1, arg2, arg3) // Returns a value
```

The **difference** lays in what happens under the hoods **when the function is called**.

#### memoize-one

- collect provided arguments
- compare arguments with the ones provided in previous call (`===`)
- **arguments** are **the same**: return cached result
- **arguments** are **NOT the same**: re-evaluate result function and return

#### reselect

- collect provided arguments
- run a set of `inputSelectors` function providing them with the collected arguments
- collect `inputSelectors` return values
- compare `inputSelectors` return values with the ones obtained in previous call (`===`)
- **values** are **the same**: return cached result
- **values** are **NOT the same**: re-evaluate result function and return

#### Conclusions

`memoize-one` is a value-based memoize utility: **memoization** is performed over the value of **provided arguments**.

`reselect` adds a further evaluation layer on top of it: **memoization** is NOT performed over arguments values BUT over the **results of a set `inputSelectors` functions** fed with those initial arguments.

It means that `reselect` selectors are easily composable since each `inputSelectors` can be another `reselect` selector.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used reselect, but memoize-one works great for me when I want to calculate something from props inside render. This is a great pattern for doing an expensive operation, like mapping a large array, on props that may change over time but also may not change on some re-renders. It ensures an expensive operation used in render is re-computed only when the inputs change. It also avoids having to use lifecycle methods like getDerivedStateFromProps (if it can be calculated from props, it probably shouldn't be on state).

```
import memoize from 'memoize-one'

class Example extends Component {

  mapList = memoize(
    (list) => list.map(item => ({text: item.text}))
  )

  render() {
    // if this.props.list hasn't changed since the last render
    // memoize-one will re-use the last return value from cache
    const mappedList = this.mapList(this.props.list)

    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

Keep in mind, in most cases, you’ll want to attach the memoized function to a component instance vs. using a static class variable. This prevents multiple instances of a component from resetting each other’s memoized keys.

[react](/questions/tagged/react) [memoization](/questions/tagged/memoization) [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `reselect`, since it was specifically designed to use with React/Redux. `memoize-one` is more like a general purpose memoization library.

It's really easy to use reselect, it just wraps your selectors:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const shopItemsSelector = state => state.shop.items;

// without reselect
const subtotalSelector = state => {
  const items = shopItemsSelector(state);
  return items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0);
}

// with reselect
const subtotalSelector = createSelector(
  shopItemsSelector, // list the selectors you need
  items => items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0) // the last argument is actual selector
)
```

Comment: Good explanation. I think reselect is mainly useful when we pass state to a function and we need to run a set of inputSelectors. Single memoization can be useful when the function accepts just a few variable arguments.